# How to get (-8)^0.333333 = -2 in MATLAB?

Tags: function, matlab, exponential

Using MATLAB exponential function:

```
(-8)^0.333333
ans = 1.0000 + 1.7320i
```

How to get `(-8)^0.333333 = -2`  instead?

```
x=-10:-1;
x.^0.333333
```

How to get real value?

How to redefine `^`:

```
x.^y
```

to

```
sign(x).*abs(x.^y))
```

Comment: You probably want to read about this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_branch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MATLAB 7.0 provides the `NTHROOT` function, which returns the real roots of a number. So your formula becomes `NTHROOT(-8, 3) = -2`

If you are using a version prior to MATLAB 7.0 (R14), please read the following:

To obtain the real cube root of a negative real number "x", rather than executing:

```
x.^(1/3)
```

use the command:

```
sign(x).*abs(x.^(1/3))
```

This will find the absolute value of the root and modify it by the sign of the argument.

[See this](http://www.mathworks.com.au/support/solutions/en/data/1-15M1N/index.html?product=ML&solution=1-15M1N)

Comment: Thank you very much. 
How to redefine ^:
x.^(1/3)
to
sign(x).*abs(x.^(1/3))

Answer (score 4):

There are 3 possible answers for the cube root of -8: `-2, 1+/- sqrt(3)`

You probably want `nthroot(-8,3) --> -2`