# How to redefine the .^ operator in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, function, operator-overloading, exponential, redefine

How can I redefine the exponential function `.^` in MATLAB? From:

```
x.^y
```

to:

```
sign(x).*abs(x.^y))
```

Comment: This question is related to [How to get (-8)^0.333333 = -2 in MATLAB ？](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577595/how-to-get-80-333333-2-in-matlab)

Comment: Yes. It is related to How to get (-8)^0.333333 = -2 in MATLAB.Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Can you redefine an arithmetic operator in MATLAB?... Yes
>
> **Should** you redefine an arithmetic operator in MATLAB?... Eh, probably not.

Why? Because every other function in MATLAB expects that the arithmetic operator will behave as defined by the built-in implementation.

I've answered a few other related questions that have dealt with overloading arithmetic operators and shadowing built-in behavior, which I definitely suggest reading through first to understand the details, difficulties, and pitfalls involved in such an approach:

- [MATLAB: Is it possible to overload operators on native constructs (cells, structs, etc)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5365464/52738)
- [How do I get real integer overflows in MATLAB/Octave?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2425251/52738)

And now that I'm done with my disclaimer, I'll hand you the gun with which to potentially shoot yourself in the foot... ;)

---

Arithmetic operators in MATLAB have functional equivalents that are called behind the scenes when you invoke them, which are listed [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/arithmetic-operators.html). The arraywise power operator `.^` calls the built-in [`power`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/power.html) function when invoked.

Now, there will be a separate `power` function defined for each [data type](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/numeric-types.html) that uses it. This function will be placed in an `@type` directory, which you can see by using the [`which`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/which.html) function to look at the different `power` functions that exist:

```
>> which power -all
built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\ops\@single\power)  % single method
built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\ops\@double\power)  % double method
built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\ops\@char\power)    % char method
built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\ops\@int64\power)   % int64 method
built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\ops\@int32\power)   % int32 method
built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\ops\@int16\power)   % int16 method
built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\ops\@int8\power)    % int8 method
built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\ops\@uint64\power)  % uint64 method
built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\ops\@uint32\power)  % uint32 method
built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\ops\@uint16\power)  % uint16 method
built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\ops\@uint8\power)   % uint8 method
```

If your variables `x` and `y` are going to be of type [`double`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.html) (as they are by default in MATLAB), then you will have to shadow the built-in `@double\power` function. You can do this by creating a directory (we'll call it `temp`), creating a subdirectory within that called `@double`, and then placing the following custom `power` function in that subdirectory:

```
function result = power(x, y)
  result = sign(x).*abs(builtin('power', x, y));
end
```

Now, based on the [function precedence order](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/function-precedence-order.html) MATLAB follows, if you add the directory `temp` to the [MATLAB path](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/what-is-the-matlab-search-path.html), or if you simply change the [current working directory](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cd.html) to `temp`, then the above custom `power` function will be called instead of the built-in one when using the `.^` operator on double variables.

Answer (score 8):

Don't.  It won't be correct.  (-1).^(1/2) should always give you the imaginary unit (i).  The expression you have would give you (-1).^(1/2) -> -1.  Even worse, consider (-1)^2.

Create a separate function to perform the operation you're describing.  Something like

```
function a = myPowerFunc(x, y)

a = sign(x).*abs(x.^y);
```